# Is that possible to import and read xml file using SAS for password protected Linux folder

Tags: linux, xml, sas, passwords, host

I wanted to import xml file using SAS from linux password protected folder (which required user,password,Host and recfm).

Currently I can import text file but not xml.

Below is the code which I used to import text file but not able to use same for xml.

```
filename Fullf ftp "&mytime."
 cd='/ABCfile/in/PROD/Step'
         user='Auser' pass = 'Pass_123' host='abcdttf.cor.abc.com'
         recfm=v prompt;
```

Any suggestion would really help. Thank you

Comment: How would you read data from that XML file if it were not password protected? Are you familiar with the XML mapper?

Comment: It is not necessary to be password protected, Here file is not protected only Linux folder and access is given to only few specified members. Not sure how to read and import.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is that you cannot use the XML libname engine with a fileref that uses the FTP engine.  The solution is to make a copy to a local file.  Then you can use the XML libname engine with that file.

```
filename Fullf ftp "&mytime."
   cd='/ABCfile/in/PROD/Step'
   user='Auser' pass = 'Pass_123' host='abcdttf.cor.abc.com'
   recfm=v prompt
;
filename xmlfile temp;
%let rc=%sysfunc(fcopy(fullf,xmlfile ));
filename xmlmap temp;
libname mylib xmlv2 xmlfileref=xmlfile xmlmap=xmlmap ;
```

Comment: We cannot push it to local folder, Yes from Local folder we can import and read files, But here we wanted to import and read from linux folder. Any method or suggestion would really help

Comment: Your comment does not make any sense.  The code I posted is reading from the FTP server, It just has to make a physical copy to enable using the XML engine.  If you want to read the file using a data step instead then you do not need to first make the physical copy.